# How to send data to another page via php

Tags: php

I want to send some data to another server but I don't want user to view the data.
I tried submitting form but others still manage to see the data even it is hidden.

PS: The server only receives `$_POST`.

Comment: use forge.js to encrypt the data in base64

Comment: you could send from the server with curl()

Comment: Did you use `method="post"` in your form tag?

Comment: How can a basic user see a POST data ? Check your form method

Answer (score 1):

You use `curl` for this purpose.

An example:

```
<?PHP
function POST($url,$data,$headers,$type)
{
    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    if($type === 1)
    {
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    }
    else
    {
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    $output = curl_exec ($ch);
    $posturl = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $cURLinfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return array(
        "output" => $output,
        "posturl" => $posturl,
        "httpcode" => $httpCode,
        "diagnostics" => $cURLinfo
    );
}
?>
```

But most likely, this is a duplicate of [How do I send a POST request with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php)

Answer (score -1):

use [forge.js](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) to encrypt the data in base64 e.g.

```
jQuery.post('yourfile.php', 
              {uname: forge.util.encode64(jQuery('#uname').val()) , 
              upass: forge.util.encode64(jQuery('#upass').val() )
              },function(data) 
                {
                    console.log(data);
                 });
```

and then in PHP you can use

```
$user =  base64_decode($_POST['uname']);
$passw =  base64_decode($_POST['upass']);
```

to retrieve the data.

Comment: OP, did ask for via PHP

Comment: I believe what he meant was while submitting data via HTML the data needs to be encrypted, and proposed a solution based on this. If OP re-confirms he is asking to do it via PHP, I will delete the post happily

Comment: "but I don't want user to view the data" - and you use Javascript? base64 is not secure anyway.